# Getting an average in a ratings system in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

Currently trying to get an overall average for each of my products based from the reviews. But my code seems to be summing all of the ratings rather than the ones where the reviews are related to the Product.

My tables are:

**Products**: id, name, price
**Reviews**: id, Review, product_id(fk), ratings_id(fk)
**ratings**: id , rating

```
class Product extends Model {

    public function reviews()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Review','products_id');
    }
  }



 class Rating extends Model
   {
    //
    public function reviews(){
        $this->hasMany('App\Review');
    }
   }

class Review extends Model
{
    //
    public function products(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
    }

    public function ratings()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Rating');
    }

}
```

**ProductsController:** :

```
   public function getSingle($slug )
    {
        //fetch from the database based on slug.
        $product = Product::where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();


        //return view
        return view('products.single')->withProduct($product);

    }
```

then my view and where i encounter the **problem** of retrieving an average of the whole rating column and not just of this product.:

```
@foreach($product->reviews as $reviews)

<h4>Rated: {{$reviews->ratings->sum('rating') / Count($product->reviews)}} </h4>
@endforeach
```

Where am i going wrong and why am i not achieving an average of a certain product reviews rating but an average of review ratings for all products.

Comment: Wouldn't `$reviews->ratings->avg("rating")` work for this?

Comment: Yes but it still gets a avg for all of the ratings and not just an average for the ratings on each review in a certain product. unfortunately

Comment: Your reviews look like they're a pivot table. You should not have a relationship for it. Join the product directly with the review. If you need pivot table data you can add them using `withPivot(["columns"])` . Alternatively  `$product->reviews->avg(function ($v) { return $v->ratings->sum("rating"); });` might work

Comment: Unfortunately that returns the same as im getting. with the code i posted.